# Angular 2 Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to wrap the Bootstrap Modal dialog in an Angular 2 component/directive/...

Not having much luck though. I've had a look at https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal but many of the APIs used there aren't available anymore in the latest release - 0.46.

I would like a service that opens/closes the dialog. In order to do so, I would need something to manipulate the DOM. Injecting a Renderer, ElementRef, etc. don't seem to suffice.

On additional caveat is that a Modal needs to insert a non-clickable backdrop so a simple component won't do since it can only influence the DOM locally.

Comment: ui.bootstrap. go for it and use it for modal popup. fortunately you can make service and call it accordingly...

Comment: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal is updated by now.. works great!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35233667/1110395