# Angular 2.0 and Modal Dialog

Tags: modal-dialog, angular

I am trying to find some examples on how to do a Confirmation modal dialog in Angular 2.0. I have been using Bootstrap dialog for Angular 1.0  and unable to find any examples in the web for Angular 2.0. I also checked angular 2.0 docs with no luck.

Is there a way to use the Bootstrap dialog with Angular 2.0?

Comment: I've found this example. Maybe it'll help you http://angularscript.com/angular2-modal-window-with-bootstrap-style/

Comment: I am using this one with RC3 and pretty content with it: https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: Thanks to @Sam, I got a good start. However, I noticed that the calling component doesn't know which button is clicked. After some research, I was able to [use Observables instead of EventEmitters to come up with a more elegant solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38962716/463059).

Comment: How about https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal ?

Comment: @mentat, url updated https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Answer (score 200, accepted):

- Angular 2 and up
- Bootstrap css (animation is preserved)
- **NO JQuery**
- **NO bootstrap.js**
- Supports **custom modal content** (just like accepted answer)
- Recently added support for **multiple modals on top of each other**.

`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
  <button type="button" (click)="modal.show()">test</button>
  <app-modal #modal>
    <div class="app-modal-header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-body">
      Whatever content you like, form fields, anything
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.hide()">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </app-modal>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `
  <div (click)="onContainerClicked($event)" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
       [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-header"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-body"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <ng-content select=".app-modal-footer"></ng-content>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})
export class ModalComponent {

  public visible = false;
  public visibleAnimate = false;

  public show(): void {
    this.visible = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 100);
  }

  public hide(): void {
    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
  }

  public onContainerClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('modal')) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

**To show the backdrop**, you'll need something like this CSS:

```
.modal {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

**The example now allows for multiple modals at the same time**. (see the `onContainerClicked()` method).

**For Bootstrap 4 css users**, you need to make 1 minor change (because a css class name was updated from Bootstrap 3). This line:
`[ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"` should be changed to:
`[ngClass]="{'show': visibleAnimate}"`

To demonstrate, here is a **[plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/7kqyiW97CI696Ixn020g/)**

Comment: There's a gotcha though. Because the buttons are wrapped inside an extra element here, the bootstrap styling won't apply margins to the buttons (at least in v4). removing the wrapping `div.modal-footer` and changing the `.app-modal-footer` to `.modal-footer` fixes this.

Answer (score 55):

Here's a pretty decent example of how you can use the Bootstrap modal within an Angular2 app on [GitHub](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal).

The gist of it is that you can wrap the bootstrap html and jquery initialization in a component. I've created a reusable `modal` component that allows you to trigger an open using a template variable.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.open()">Open me!</button>

<modal #modal>
    <modal-header [show-close]="true">
        <h4 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>
        Hello World!
    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer [show-default-buttons]="true"></modal-footer>
</modal>
```

You just need to install the npm package and register the modal module in your app module:

```
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

@NgModule({
    imports: [Ng2Bs3ModalModule]
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

Comment: Bummer - relies on jquery as a dependency :(

Comment: Well yeah, bootstrap relies on it and I'm not in the business of rewriting libraries.

Comment: This can be done without jQuery. I used Sam's answer along with the tutorial at http://koscielniak.me/post/2016/03/angular2-confirm-dialog-component/ to write a service and associated modal component.

Comment: If you are not using bootstrap in your project do not forget to add link to bootstrap.css. The github page forgets to mention this.

Answer (score 46):

This is a simple approach that does not depend on jquery or any other library except Angular 2.
The component below (errorMessage.ts) can be used as a child view of any other component.  It is simply a bootstrap modal that is always open or shown.  It's visibility is governed by the ngIf statement.

errorMessage.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-error-message',
    templateUrl: './app/common/errorMessage.html',
})
export class ErrorMessage
{
    private ErrorMsg: string;
    public ErrorMessageIsVisible: boolean;

    showErrorMessage(msg: string)
    {
        this.ErrorMsg = msg;
        this.ErrorMessageIsVisible = true;
    }

    hideErrorMsg()
    {
        this.ErrorMessageIsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

errorMessage.html

```
<div *ngIf="ErrorMessageIsVisible" class="modal fade show in danger" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{{ErrorMsg}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="hideErrorMsg()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an example parent control (some non-relevant code has been omitted for brevity):

parent.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/common';
import {Router, RouteSegment, OnActivate, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-application-detail',
    templateUrl: './app/permissions/applicationDetail.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ErrorMessage]  // Note ErrorMessage is a directive
})
export class ApplicationDetail implements OnActivate
{
    @ViewChild(ErrorMessage) errorMsg: ErrorMessage;  // ErrorMessage is a ViewChild



    // yada yada


    onSubmit()
    {
        let result = this.permissionsService.SaveApplication(this.Application).subscribe(x =>
        {
            x.Error = true;
            x.Message = "This is a dummy error message";

            if (x.Error) {
                this.errorMsg.showErrorMessage(x.Message);
            }
            else {
                this.router.navigate(['/applicationsIndex']);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

parent.html

```
<app-error-message></app-error-message>
// your html...
```

Comment: nice - could explain `class="modal fade show in danger"`

Comment: @bensiu I'm guessing that class selector is not used - unless they have a css style selectors for all those words e.g. 'in'

Comment: How do you get the fade in/out effect with this?

Answer (score 10):

#### Now available as a [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-custom-modal)

**[angular-custom-modal](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-custom-modal)**

---

@Stephen Paul [continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144809/2013580)...

- *Angular 2 and up Bootstrap css (animation is preserved)*
- *NO JQuery*
- *NO bootstrap.js*
- *Supports custom modal content*
- *Support for multiple modals on top of each
  other.*
- **Moduralized**
- **Disable scroll when modal is open**
- **Modal gets destroyed when navigating away.**
- **Lazy content initialization, which gets `ngOnDestroy`(ed) when the modal is exited.**
- **Parent scrolling disabled when modal is visible**

### Lazy content initialization

**Why?**

In some cases you might not want to modal to retain its status after having been closed, but rather restored to the initial state.

**Original modal issue**

Passing the content straightforward into the view actually generates initializes it even before the modal gets it. The modal doesn't have a way to kill such content even if using a `*ngIf` wrapper.

**Solution**

`ng-template`. `ng-template` doesn't render until ordered to do so.

my-component.module.ts

```
...
imports: [
  ...
  ModalModule
]
```

my-component.ts

```
<button (click)="reuseModal.open()">Open</button>
<app-modal #reuseModal>
  <ng-template #header></ng-template>
  <ng-template #body>
    <app-my-body-component>
      <!-- This component will be created only when modal is visible and will be destroyed when it's not. -->
    </app-my-body-content>
    <ng-template #footer></ng-template>
</app-modal>
```

modal.component.ts

```
export class ModalComponent ... {
  @ContentChild('header') header: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('body') body: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('footer') footer: TemplateRef<any>;
 ...
}
```

modal.component.html

```
<div ... *ngIf="visible">
  ...
  <div class="modal-body">
    ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="body"></ng-container>
  </div>
```

**References**

I have to say that it wouldn't have been possible without the excellent official and community documentation around the net. It might help some of you too to understand better how `ng-template`, `*ngTemplateOutlet` and `@ContentChild` work.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/
https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b
https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e
https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

### Full copy-paste solution

modal.component.html

```
<div
  (click)="onContainerClicked($event)"
  class="modal fade"
  tabindex="-1"
  [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
  [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}"
  *ngIf="visible">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="header"></ng-container>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="body"></ng-container>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="footer"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal.component.ts

```
/**
 * @Stephen Paul https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144809/2013580
 * @zurfyx https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949848/2013580
 */
import { Component, OnDestroy, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: 'modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['modal.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @ContentChild('header') header: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('body') body: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('footer') footer: TemplateRef<any>;

  public visible = false;
  public visibleAnimate = false;

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Prevent modal from not executing its closing actions if the user navigated away (for example,
    // through a link).
    this.close();
  }

  open(): void {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

    this.visible = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true, 200);
  }

  close(): void {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';

    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 100);
  }

  onContainerClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('modal')) {
      this.close();
    }
  }
}
```

modal.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [ModalComponent],
  declarations: [ModalComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class ModalModule { }
```

Answer (score 7):

I use [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) for my project.

You can find the demo [here](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

The github is [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)

How to use:

1. Install [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)
2. Import to your module

> ```
> // RECOMMENDED (doesn't work with system.js)
> import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
> // or
> import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
> })
> export class AppModule(){}
> ```

3. Simple static modal

> ```
> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="staticModal.show()">Static modal</button>
> <div class="modal fade" bsModal #staticModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
> tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
> <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
>    <div class="modal-content">
>       <div class="modal-header">
>          <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Static modal</h4>
>          <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="staticModal.hide()">
>          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
>          </button>
>       </div>
>       <div class="modal-body">
>          This is static modal, backdrop click will not close it.
>          Click <b>&times;</b> to close modal.
>       </div>
>    </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my full implementation of modal bootstrap angular2 component:

I assume that in your main index.html file (with `<html>` and `<body>` tags) at the bottom of `<body>` tag you have:

```
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

modal.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;// this is very importnant (to work this line: this.modalEl.modal('show')) - don't do this (becouse this owerride jQuery which was changed by bootstrap, included in main html-body template): let $ = require('../../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.html',
})
export class Modal implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() title:string;
    @Input() showClose:boolean = true;
    @Output() onClose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    modalEl = null;
    id: string = uniqueId('modal_');

    constructor(private _rootNode: ElementRef) {}

    open() {
        this.modalEl.modal('show');
    }

    close() {
        this.modalEl.modal('hide');
    }

    closeInternal() { // close modal when click on times button in up-right corner
        this.onClose.next(null); // emit event
        this.close();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.modalEl = $(this._rootNode.nativeElement).find('div.modal');
    }

    has(selector) {
        return $(this._rootNode.nativeElement).find(selector).length;
    }
}

let modal_id: number = 0;
export function uniqueId(prefix: string): string {
    return prefix + ++modal_id;
}
```

modal.html:

```
<div class="modal inmodal fade" id="{{modal_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true" #thisModal>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" [ngClass]="{'hide': !(has('mhead') || title) }">
                <button *ngIf="showClose" type="button" class="close" (click)="closeInternal()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <ng-content select="mhead"></ng-content>
                <h4 *ngIf='title' class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer" [ngClass]="{'hide': !has('mfoot') }" >
                <ng-content select="mfoot"></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And example of usage in client Editor component:
client-edit-component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from './client.service';
import { Modal } from '../common';

@Component({
  selector: 'client-edit',
  directives: [ Modal ],
  templateUrl: './client-edit.html',
  providers: [ ClientService ]
})
export class ClientEdit {

    _modal = null;

    constructor(private _ClientService: ClientService) {}

    bindModal(modal) {this._modal=modal;}

    open(client) {
        this._modal.open();
        console.log({client});
    }

    close() {
        this._modal.close();
    }

}
```

client-edit.html:

```
<modal [title]='"Some standard title"' [showClose]='true' (onClose)="close()" #editModal>{{ bindModal(editModal) }}
    <mhead>Som non-standart title</mhead>
    Some contents
    <mfoot><button calss='btn' (click)="close()">Close</button></mfoot>
</modal>
```

Ofcourse `title`, `showClose`, `<mhead>` and `<mfoot>` ar optional parameters/tags.

Comment: Instead of `bindModal(modal) {this._modal=modal;}`, you can use angular's [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html) annotation, like so: `@ViewChild('editModal') _modal: Modal;`. It handles the binding for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Check ASUI dialog which create at runtime. There is no need of hide and show logic. Simply service will create a component at runtime using AOT
[ASUI NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asui)

Comment: Hi Aravind Sivam, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Answer (score 0):

try to use ng-window, it's allow developer to open and full control multiple windows in single page applications in simple way, No Jquery, No Bootstrap.

[image]

Avilable Configration

- Maxmize window
- Minimize window
- Custom size,
- Custom posation
- the window is dragable
- Block parent window or not
- Center the window or not
- Pass values to chield window
- Pass values from chield window to parent window
- Listening to closing chield window in parent window
- Listen to resize event with your custom listener
- Open with maximum size or not
- Enable and disable window resizing
- Enable and disable maximization
- Enable and disable minimization

Comment: -1 How is this useful at all? It does not address any of the requirements as specified by the OP. This is the 4th post I see you trolling your answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 7 + NgBootstrap**

A simple way of opening modal from main component and passing result back to it. is what I wanted. I created a step-by-step tutorial which includes creating a new project from scratch, installing ngbootstrap and creation of Modal. You can either clone it or follow the guide.

Hope this helps new to Angular.!

https://github.com/wkaczurba/modal-demo

**Details:**

modal-simple template (modal-simple.component.html):

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Are you sure?</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You have not finished reading my code. Are you sure you want to close?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('yes')">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('no')">No</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**The modal-simple.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-simple',
  templateUrl: './modal-simple.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-simple.component.css']
})
export class ModalSimpleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('content') content;
  @Output() result : EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private modalService : NgbModal) { }

  open() {
    this.modalService.open(this.content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-simple-title'})
      .result.then((result) => { console.log(result as string); this.result.emit(result) }, 
        (reason) => { console.log(reason as string); this.result.emit(reason) })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Demo of it (app.component.html) - simple way of dealing with return event:**

```
<app-modal-simple #mymodal (result)="onModalClose($event)"></app-modal-simple>
<button (click)="mymodal.open()">Open modal</button>

<p>
Result is {{ modalCloseResult }}
</p>
```

**app.component.ts - onModalClosed is executed once modal is closed:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  modalCloseResult : string;
  title = 'modal-demo';

  onModalClose(reason : string) {
    this.modalCloseResult = reason;
  }    
}
```

Cheers