# Angular2 call a great grand parent's method from a child component

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement the modal dialog as shown in this post, but I need to call `modal.show()` from a child several layers below the parent of the modal dialog. I have no idea how to handle this.

[Angular 2.0 and Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service for showing modal rather than calling parent. And the modal should be dynamically created and destroyed.

Comment: I get the service part. I don't know what you mean about created and destroyed dynamically.

Comment: Here's an example of how to create a dynamic component: http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/ What I meant is the service will generate (or tell the parent using Event or Observable ...) to generate a modal component dynamically.

Comment: I'm a little further away from understanding this fully than I thought. This example does not use a service exactly, and I am having trouble translating this code into a shared service implementation.