# Angular2 - how to make confirm modal and reuse it from a service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

**This is not the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog)**, I would like to know how to create a reusable modal without having the modal component in all pages.

**Angular2**

In component based architecture, to make a resuable `confirm-modal` component, we need to add the component `confirm-modal` in all pages. The code for `confirm-modal` looks like this

```
@Component({
 selector: 'confirm-modal',
 exportAs: 'confirmModal',
 template: ``
})
export class ConfirmModal {
 // functions
 show() {}
}
```

So every time when I need a confirm modal in any view, I need to explicitly add `confirm-modal` in the page and use `@ViewChild(confirmModal) cm` to access the confirm modal apis like show, hide, confirm etc.

I would like to avoid adding this component html in all pages. Is there any  way to do this in angular2.

In **Angular1.5**

We use angular-bootstrap modal, the code looks like this

```
$uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  appendTo: parentElem,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $ctrl.items;
    }
  }
});
```

So, here I just need to mention the template url and resolve refers to `@Inputs` in angular2. I would like to have a similar approach in angular2.

I thought of creating a `injectable service` in angular2 and use `sevice.show()` to simply show the modal in any view. But I understand without component we cant show the template.

Comment: You can take a look at ng-bootstrap for Angular 4 (if you can upgrade to that version of Angular). It has a [modalService](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) and you can pass a component class to it. If you define a `ConfirmModal` component, you could set a different message/question each time you show the confirm modal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.0 and Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog)

Comment: @Dmitriy - This is not the duplicate of the question you have mentioned. Please go through the description once and decide whether it is duplicate or not.