# Embed pdf in Angular2 component

Tags: angular, pdf

In angular 4.3 I want to open a modal popup and show an embedded pdf file, like shown here: https://pdfobject.com/static.html

I used the [modal popup component from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog/40144809#40144809) which pops up nicely. My test html for the modal looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="setContent();modal.show()">Show</a>
<app-modal #modal>
  <div class="app-modal-header">
    Testing pdf embedding
  </div>
  <div class="app-modal-body">
    <div class="embed-responsive" *ngIf="ContentUrl">
      <object [attr.data]="ContentUrl"
              type="application/pdf"
              class="embed-responsive-item">
        <embed [attr.src]="ContentUrl"
               type="application/pdf" />
      </object>
    </div>
    <p><a [href]="ContentUrl">PDF Download</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="app-modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.hide()">Close</button>
  </div>
</app-modal>
```

In my component I set `ContentUrl` like this:

```
public ContentUrl: SafeUrl;
public setContent() {
    this.ContentUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("/img/test.pdf");
}
```

The popup opens nicely, but it does not show the embedded pdf. It does not even try to load the url from the service. The download link works nicely and asks if the pdf should be saved to disc or opened.
I tried to embed the pdf outside of the popup to no avail, too.
I tried Chrome, Edge and IE. None displays the embedded pdf.

So how do I show/embed a pdf in an angular component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up creating the `object` using innerHtml.

In the template:

```
<div *ngIf="innerHtml"
  [innerHTML]="innerHtml">
</div>
```

In the code behind:

```
public innerHtml: SafeHtml;
public setInnerHtml(pdfurl: string) {
    this.innerHtml = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
        "<object data='" + pdfurl + "' type='application/pdf' class='embed-responsive-item'>" +
        "Object " + pdfurl + " failed" +
        "</object>");
}
```

This way the object already has it's data attribute set upon creation. At least now the PDF is embedded like I wanted to.

Comment: is it okay to bypass sanitizer if we know that the html we are injecting is fine?

Comment: Aiguo, I don't understand your question or your implications.

Comment: what I'm referring to is that you are using "this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml.." to inject object html into the view. So I'm just concerned and curious about by passing the sanitizer.

Comment: Ah, ok. Every part of the html is created by the program, even the pdfurl. No user input is used for creating the html. So I see no reason to clean the html up.
This would be different if user entered data was used in the html, of course.

Comment: I am still getting this error `Refused to display 'MYFULLLINK' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny`

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me in angular 9

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser'

public innerHtml: any;

constructor(
private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
) { }

const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(result);

  this.innerHtml = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
    "<object data='" + fileURL + "' type='application/pdf' class='embed-responsive-item'>" +
    "Object " + fileURL + " failed" +
    "</object>");
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yU83.png)