# how to open ng bootstrap modals from another component?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to open or close modals from Another Module with the help of component 1. But currently I am unable to access the modalRef of ngBootstrap of the modals in that component so that I can close/open it.

Suppose this scenerio

**One Module**

```
<component1></component1>
```

**Another Module**
this module have multiple components and each component have modal in it which I need to show or hide based on the conditions from component 1.

```
<component2> //have ng bootstrap modal in it </component2>
<component3> //have ng bootstrap modal in it </component3>
<component4> //have ng bootstrap modal in it </component4>
<component5> //have ng bootstrap modal in it </component5>
<component6> //have ng bootstrap modal in it </component6>
```

Currently I am doing this by just putting one hidden button in that module and the click it using the JavaScript from another component, I know that this is not a good approach so I want someone to give me some approach to calling these modals or tell me if there is anything to change in the design.

As far as I know I think service will be good to do this. But before changing the design I want someone opinion. Thanks

Comment: Your description is quite vague, and doesn't make much sense (modules don't contain buttons). Post a complete minimal example, as a plunkr, reproducing the problem.

Comment: you need to include `NgbModule` in to your other module as well so that it will ve available.

Comment: Modules have no button actually its  template have buttons. The question is quite simple in the above scenerio how can I open and close the modal from another module. Because currently I am unable to access the modalRef in that component to close it. Kindly tell me if you want more clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service with `Observable` and trigger and emit which user click on the close button.

Once the close button clicked, the event can be catched in any other component and action can be performed.

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
   public popup: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {}
}
```

**Component** which have modal to close.

```
constructor(SomeService: SomeService){
  this.SomeService.popup.subscribe((val)=>{
     if(val === 'close') {
       // close the modal
     }
   });
}
```

And now from the other component, you can trigger the event to close the model. you can perform the close from any component.

```
constructor(private SomeService: SomeService) {}

SomeMethod() {
  this.someService.popup.next('close');
}
```

Comment: Please tell me that what is Subject in the example and how this service is pointing to modelRef of the modal in the components

Comment: `Subject` or `BevavourSubject` are observable type variable available in angulr to trigger events which can be caught by any other event. you can follow this link to see more -- https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

Comment: Thanks for your time. I thinks that this is the solution of my problem but my application grew big with this foolish hidden button approach. I will apply your solution on my app and if this solves the problem then I will accept it.

Comment: sure, make sure to accept or up vote if it resolve your problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the (//close the modal) comment. In short how this service is linked (or have references) to the modal in component so that I can open or close it.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across the same problem and found this thread, ***Aniruddha Das*** did a great job of highlighting the basic requirements but I found it missed the TemplateRef usage which is the next bit and just in case anyone else has this issue I'll finish it. using the same model as Aniruddha's

**Template:**

```
<ng-template #updatemodal>
  <div class="modal">
    stuff here...
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Component:**

```
@ViewChild('updatemodal')
private modalRef: TemplateRef<any>;

private myModal<any>;

constructor(SomeService: SomeService, modalService: NgbModal){
  this.SomeService.popup.subscribe((val)=>{
     if(val === 'open') {
       this.myModal = this.modalService.open(this.modalRef);
     }
   });
}
```

Referencing the modal that has been created is a great way to allow more use and flexibility within the response and by using:

```
this.myModal.result.then((result) =>{
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
```

from the [NgBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) site

Answer (score 1):

1. In `app.module.ts`:

   ```
   {
       ...
       imports [...],
       entryComponents: [ModalComponent],
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Write your model, as part "Components as content" from [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples).
3. In the component where you use the modal:

   - import ModalComponent and dependencies
   - constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)
   - preferable put this into a method:

     ```
     const modal = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
     modal.componentInstance.title = "Dialog";
     modal.componentInstance.body = "Your message";
     ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `NgbModule` is available to the module and not other module in your application. When when imports a module ( here `NgbModule`) it is specific to that module only. So either you have to include `NgbModule` in the other module or export that in the current module and import current module in the other module.

import it in the other module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
  ],
```

Or import the first module in the secound which already included the `NgbModule` module.

Comment: I can open and close modals there is no problem in this. In the above scenerio how can I close modal from any component of another module from component 1.

Comment: Ohh, are they parent child or parellel

Comment: Some are parent child and some are parrellel. I am able to access modals from child using ViewChild property but I am unable to access modals which are in parallels (In other module).

Comment: You can create a service with observable and emit an event to catch it when you want to close it. Let me put another answer.

Comment: See my other answer

Answer (score -3):

See this answer , you can create a custom modal without any external library:
[Angular 2.0 and Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog)

Comment: Sorry I want the solution using ngBootstrap.