# my first Modal in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

If I using AngularJS I should make modal in CSS? or can I make in AngularJS? There is finished solutions to use?

Can someone tell me in what and how best to do it ?

I dont ask for a solution but only for some information how to catch it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.0 and Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog)

Comment: AngularJS !== Angular 2/4

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of pre defined libraries you can use, I can suggest using: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal or https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: Hey thanks for link, but what If I using Angular 1, I can inject this bootstrap??? And how does it come with the bootstrap included by the link

Comment: The first link is specifically for Angular 1, yo can inject and use it as any other library.

Comment: If i will inject it into my project, then I have to delete bootstraps included my tags scripts yes?

Comment: You can have both, but it's preferable if you only use one (the angular one) to keep consistency

Comment: ok can u tell me only what is differences between this libraries??

Comment: The first one is for angular 1, the other for angular 2

Comment: hey thanks, but I mean what is differences between bootstrap for angular 1 and bootstrap 3 without using any frameworks