# Angular 2+ Modal/Popover form

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to add a popover-style div to collect form data from a user. Maybe four fields, then they close the popover and return to the page. If they have another record of data to enter, then the popover opens again and closes when they submit the data successfully.

I would previously do this with jQuery but I don't know how I would do this in a mobile-responsive way. I am using Boostrap as well.

Any suggestions/recommendations? Below is an example of a simple popover div form I'd made in the past, and am trying to reproduce in Angular.

[image]

Comment: which version of angular? version 2 or 1?

Comment: 4 actually, so 2+. i'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog

Comment: this link might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog

Comment: thank you @KhaledAhmed, i use bootbox for simple modal/confirm type dialogs but have to make a form. Sam gave a good example using Angular Material for more complicated dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an [angular material dialogue](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

I like the bootstrap modal too, but I think angular material is easier to get started with. You will need [flexbox](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) for the layout with material if you are not using bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I am installing this and will try making my dialog with this.