# Angular 2 - Open/Close default bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I do not want to use [angular2-bootstrap](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal) or [ng2-bs3-modal](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal) as suggested in the questions/answers [Angular 2 Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993310/angular-2-bootstrap-modal)  and [Angular 2.0 and Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog/35233667#35233667)

Now. I know what opens and closes the bootstrap modal.

- The display is toggled between `display: none;` and `display: block;`
- An attribute toggles on the `div` between `aria-hidden="true"` and `aria-hidden="false`

So, naturally I thought that if I bound to the `aria-hidden` attribute like so `[aria-hidden]="true"`, that I could manipulate it. Sadly though, I cannot bind to `aria-hidden` since it isn't a known property of `div`. (note, `attr.aria-hidden` doesn't exist)

I do know that this is possible with JQuery with `$('#myModal').modal()` as shown in this question [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

So my question is, is there a TypeScript functionality that does the same thing as `modal()` from JQuery, or is there a way to bind a function/variable to `aria-hidden`?

My current `html`:

```
<div id="createAccountModal" class="modal fade customForm" role="dialog" [aria-hidden]="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Create account</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <p>Lorem ipsum</P>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer align-left">
                My custom footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: have you tried this : aria-hidden="{{yourVariable}}"

Comment: @xe4me nope, throws the same `Cannot bind to 'aria-hidden' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`. Found the answer though

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try something like this, create `myModal.html`:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" [style.display]="showModal ? 'block' : 'none'"></div>
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block" [style.display]="showModal ? 'block' : 'none'">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-popup">
          <div class="popup-title">
            <span>{{title}} </span>
            <i class="icon-cancel fr" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="cancelAction()"></i>
            <p *ngIf="subTitle">{{subTitle}}</p>
          </div>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then, create `myModal.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const template: string = require('./myModal.html');

@Component({
   selector: 'modal',
   template
})

export class Modal implements OnInit {
  @Input('show-modal') showModal: boolean;
  @Input('title') title: string;
  @Input('sub-title') subTitle: string;
  @Input('cancel-label') cancelLabel: string;
  @Input('positive-label') positiveLabel: string;

  @Output('closed') closeEmitter: EventEmitter < ModalResult > = new EventEmitter < ModalResult > ();
  @Output('loaded') loadedEmitter: EventEmitter < Modal > = new EventEmitter < Modal > ();
  @Output() positiveLabelAction = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadedEmitter.next(this);
  }

  show() {
    this.showModal = true;
  }

  hide() {
    this.showModal = false;
    this.closeEmitter.next({
      action: ModalAction.POSITIVE
    });
  }

  positiveAction() {
    this.positiveLabelAction.next(this);
    return false;
  }

  cancelAction() {
    this.showModal = false;
    this.closeEmitter.next({
      action: ModalAction.CANCEL
    });
    return false;
  }
}

export enum ModalAction { POSITIVE, CANCEL }

export interface ModalResult {
  action: ModalAction;
}
```

then create **module** for this so that you can use anywhere and use it anywhere like this:

```
<modal #deleteUserModal id="deleteUser"
   [show-modal]="isModalOpen"
   [title]="'Delete'"
   >
  <div class="popup-content">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete the user permanently?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-footer">
    <button class="btn cancel"  aria-label="Close" (click)="deleteUserModal.hide()">
        Cancel
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteSelectedUser(deleteUserModal)" aria-label="Close">
        Delete
    </button>
   </div>
 </modal>
```

You can enhance this also :)

Comment: aside from some wrong bootstrap css classes this works like a charm.

Comment: how to call the modal in component.ts

Answer (score 9):

if your modal has a cancel button (Otherwise create a hidden close button). You can simulate the click event on this button so that your form is closed.
Iin your component add a **ViewChild**

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput:ElementRef;
```

in your close button add **#fileInput**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" #fileInput id="delete-node" name="button" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit">Cancelar</button>
```

When you want to close the modal programmatically trigger an click event on the close button

```
this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
```

To open you can use the same idea

Comment: Thanks for save my time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out there's no need to bind to `aria-hidden` although this should be possible I guess.

The current answer came from [Angular 2.0 and Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513558/angular-2-0-and-modal-dialog/35233667#35233667) (but a answer with only 9 upvotes)

Adding

```
<div id="createAccountModal" class="modal fade customForm" role="dialog" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
       [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">
```

This to my code, and having a `(click)` handler on a button toggle the `visible` and `visibleAnimate` suited my needs.

Answer (score -1):

try to use ng-window, it's allow developer to open and full control multiple windows in single page applications in simple way, No Jquery, No Bootstrap.

[image]

Avilable Configration

- Maxmize window
- Minimize window
- Custom size,
- Custom posation
- the window is dragable
- Block parent window or not
- Center the window or not
- Pass values to chield window
- Pass values from chield window to parent window
- Listening to closing chield window in parent window
- Listen to resize event with your custom listener
- Open with maximum size or not
- Enable and disable window resizing
- Enable and disable maximization
- Enable and disable minimization